# Issue with an Error using Arrays and For Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Been having problem with an error I can't figure out, and could really need some help.

> Error #1069: Property 0 not found on Number and there is no default value.

```
var arenaer:Array = new Array ();
    arenaer[0] = "SJUSJØEN";
    arenaer[1] = "SKEI";
    arenaer[2] = "HAFJELL";
    arenaer[3] = "KVITFJELL";
    arenaer[4] = "GÅLÅ";
    arenaer[5] = "KVAMSFJELLET";
    arenaer[6] = "LEMONSJØEN";
    arenaer[7] = "MYSUSETER";
    arenaer[8] = "HØVRINGEN";

var dybde:Array = new Array();
    dybde[0] = (16,23);
    dybde[1] = (12,17);
    dybde[2] = (34,55);
    dybde[3] = (22,34);
    dybde[4] = (16,43);
    dybde[5] = (28,21);
    dybde[6] = (29,33);
    dybde[7] = (27,57);
    dybde[8] = (17,6);

var info:Array = new Array();
    info[0] = "SNØDYBDE(CM)";
    info[1] = "LØYPER(KM)";

btnvis.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vis);

function vis (evt:MouseEvent)
{
    var i:int;
    var j:int;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        txtarena.appendText(arenaer[i] + "     ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        txtinfo.appendText(info[i] + "\n\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <9; j++)
        {
            txtarena.appendText(dybde [i][j]+ "    ");
        }
        txtarena.appendText("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know where you're getting the error.

Comment: This is the OUTPUT "comment":

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on Number and there is no default value.
 at ARRAY_fla::MainTimeline/vis()

Comment: It looks like a problem with an array. How are your arrays defined?

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to tag this as an Actionscript question.

Comment: var arenaer:Array = new Array ();
arenaer [0] = "SJUSJØEN";
arenaer [1] = "SKEI";
arenaer [2] = "HAFJELL";
arenaer [3] = "KVITFJELL";
arenaer [4] = "GÅLÅ";
arenaer [5] = "KVAMSFJELLET";
arenaer [6] = "LEMONSJØEN";
arenaer [7] = "MYSUSETER";
arenaer [8] = "HØVRINGEN";




var dybde:Array = new Array();
dybde[0] = (16,23);
dybde[1] = (12,17);
dybde[2] = (34,55);
dybde[3] = (22,34);
dybde[4] = (16,43);
dybde[5] = (28,21);
dybde[6] = (29,33);
dybde[7] = (27,57);
dybde[8] = (17,6);



var info:Array = new Array();
info [0] = "SNØDYBDE(CM)";
info [1] = "LØYPER(KM)";

Comment: The initialization of `dybde` looks screwy. The code implies that it's a nine-element array of nine-element arrays, but the initialization for that would look something like `dybde[0] = [16, 23, 30, 37, 44, 51, 58, 65, 72];` (Note the square brackets.)

Comment: We went through an "almost " identical code in the class , so I do not quite understand why it's not working .
Tried with your proposal :
TypeError : Error # 1010 : A term is undefined and has no properties.
that ARRAY_fla :: Main Timeline / Show ( )

Comment: I really would like to show you the "Program" we in class...

Comment: Well, that's not the only issue. There's also the issue of trying to add a string to a number, but my Actionscript is a little rusty, and since no one else is taking a crack at it, I'm doing the best I can.

Comment: Anyway, try `txtarena.appendText(String(dybde[i][j])+ "    ");`. That will cast the number to a string so it can be concatenated.

Comment: Ah... Didnt work... Got the same Error. 
I'm really greatful that you're trying to help me :)
("Just started with AS3, having hard time learning.)

Comment: You're still getting the #1010 error, then? That's in code you haven't provided, unfortunately.

Comment: Please post all of your code as part of you question, not as comments,  that makes it easier for other to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Still get the : TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at ARRAY_fla::MainTimeline/vis()

Comment: What are you trying to do?  As others have noted, the code you've posted is *really* screwy, so it's hard to figure out where you've went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dybde:Array = new Array();
    dybde[0] = (16,23);
    dybde[1] = (12,17);
//...etc
```

this code should not compile I think. What are you trying to put into the Array? Every index can hold one item, not two. Looks like you're trying to do this:

```
 dybde[0] = new Point(16,23);
```

or

```
dybde[0] = [16, 23]; // make it two-dimensional
```

But you're not telling us what line your error is on, so it may still be something else.

Comment: It will compile, but it's clearly wrong.  From http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/syntax.html, "you can use parentheses with the comma operator to evaluate a series of expressions and return the result of the final expression."  All the "dybde" assignments are simply resolving to the second number in the pairs, e.g. `dybde[0] = 23;`  Then the line `txtarena.appendText(dybde [i][j]+ "    ");` is trying to call 23[0], which doesn't exist.

Comment: So you want me to add all the number on one?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish but if you implement my second solution (with the square brackets instead of the round ones, to make a two-dimensional Array) your code might work. Then go ask your teacher to explain Arrays once more.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your mouse in variable dybde[0] you can see the value of variable. In your case your variable is with only a value. You can search "matrix actionscript" or change your code to:

```
        var dybde:Array = new Array();
        dybde[0] = [16,23];
        dybde[1] = [12,17];
        dybde[2] = [34,55];
        dybde[3] = [22,34];
        dybde[4] = [16,43];
        dybde[5] = [28,21];
        dybde[6] = [29,33];
        dybde[7] = [27,57];
        dybde[8] = [17,6];
```